# Process All Rows in Javascript Step

Tags: pentaho, kettle

How do I read and process all the rows that read from an excel, in Javascript step.

I have the following transformation

[image]

The first step is to read all the rows from a spreadsheet and then I will post it to a REST service. I am waiting for the REST operation is to complete before entering the JS script. In the JS step, I want to process all the records at a time and save it as one single record to XML.

Just to give some more clarity on my requirement, I will give one scenario. I have an input file with two columns. Material no and quantity. After the JavaScript step, I need to post the data read from the spreadsheet to another service. This service will return me the free goods associated with the input. But to get free good, I need a combination of materials. For eg: if the input is TV and DVD Player, I get something free. But I won't get anything free, if I am passing only TV or DVD player as the input. So in this case my data is:

```
**Material    Qty**
TV            1
DVD Player    1
```

My REST service has the following structure.

```
{
    "items": [
        {  
         "material":"TV",
         "quantity":"1",
        },
        {  
         "material":"DVD Player",
         "quantity":"1",
        }
    ]
}
```

Any input on how to achieve this would be really valuable. Thank you.

Comment: Why do you need to wait for the REST to finish ?

Comment: The requirement is to process all the rows in the modified JavaScript at a time. So I need to wait for all the rows to be processed before reaching to JavasScript step.

Answer (score 0):

One way of addressing this in a transformation is to use a group by. Try using `unique rows by hashset` or even a `group by` utility.

This step will replace the blocking step and wait until all rows are processed and grouped.

Below is the sample (3 ways)
[image: Grouping_dataset]

As an example, the `Unique Rows (Hashset)` can read all the fields from the JavaScript which will make it distinct after reading the entire dataset.

Comment: Tried both and I still not sure how can I process all the rows in my JS script. Can you please give little more details on how to access it.

Comment: Sorry for not communicating properly. I have updated the question now. The requirement is to process all the records at a time in JS step. So if the spreadsheet has 10 rows, when we reach the JS step, there would be 10 rows and I would like to process all of them at a time.

Comment: Then just add the group by before JavaScript call. You dont need the blocking step btw

Comment: Still it won't help me in processing all the rows at a time in my JS step. I have updated the question with a scenario and an example. Please have a look.

Comment: Just add the columns material and qty in the unique rows as per the first solution. It should work